# Maven co-ordinates for commons dbcp 2.0

Tags: maven, apache-commons-dbcp

I want to use Commons-DBCP 2.0.
On official site i found:

> Users upgrading to 2.x should be aware that the Java package name has changed, as well as the Maven co-ordinates, since DBCP 2.x is not binary compatible with DBCP 1.x.

But what are the new coordinates? As expected [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp) are only 1.x available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it this one?

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Most apache projects have aligned with the `org.apache.commons` groupid.
And you seemed to want the DBCP 2.

And BTW, maven central has its own search facility:

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|commons-dbcp

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile i looked into source to get co-ordinates. In future i will use the search you mentioned instead of mvnrepository.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maven central repository  : [central maven search](http://search.maven.org/).

In your case [commons-dbcp2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-dbcp2%7C2.0%7Cjar).